# Combining elements of two lists as key:value pairs in a dictionary goes wrong. Python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, python-3.5

I have two lists:

```
lists1 = [(0, 75), (75, 38), (38, 86), (86, 119), (119, 85), (85, 44), (44, 65), (65, 127)]
list2 = [12.0, 16.0, 17.0, 6.0, 31.0, 45.0, 13.0, 27.0]
```

Both has same length (8)

```
list_dict = dict(zip(list1,list2))
```

Reports

```
{(0, 75): 12.0, (119, 85): 31.0, (86, 119): 6.0, (38, 86): 17.0, (44, 65): 13.0, (85, 44): 45.0, (75, 38): 16.0, (65, 127): 27.0}
```

What i am looking for is,

```
{(0, 75): 12.0, (75, 38): 16.0,(38, 86): 17.0,(86, 119): 6.0,(119, 85): 31.0,  (85, 44): 45.0, (44, 65): 13.0 , (65, 127): 27.0}
```

How to do it? Why the index has changed?

Comment: Dicts do not promise to preserve order.

Comment: By index do you mean ordering? `dict` does not preserve ordering. If you need ordered dictionary use `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: @Tuwuh That works! I am not aware of it. You can update it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By index do you mean ordering? `dict` does not preserve ordering. If you need ordered dictionary use `collections.OrderedDict`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
list_dict = OrderedDict(zip(lists1,list2))
```

That gave me:

```
>>> list_dict

OrderedDict([((0, 75), 12.0),
             ((75, 38), 16.0),
             ((38, 86), 17.0),
             ((86, 119), 6.0),
             ((119, 85), 31.0),
             ((85, 44), 45.0),
             ((44, 65), 13.0),
             ((65, 127), 27.0)])
```

Answer (score 3):

You may notice that the `zip` matches your elements just fine. So that only leaves the `dictionary` to contain some problem. And that is in fact the crux of your problem here.

**Dictionaries are not Ordered!** And that's why there is a chance that when you print out your `dictionary`, the order **may** change.

So just use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) , and it should solve your problems.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict(zip(l1, l2))
>>> d
=> OrderedDict([((0, 75), 12.0), ((75, 38), 16.0), ((38, 86), 17.0), ((86, 119), 6.0), ((119, 85), 31.0), ((85, 44), 45.0), ((44, 65), 13.0), ((65, 127), 27.0)])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no order on the indices of dictionaries: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs [...]

and

> Performing `list(d.keys())` on a dictionary returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order (if you want it sorted, just use `sorted(d.keys())` instead)

So just sort the keys when you need to traverse them in that order:

```
>>> for k in sorted(list_dict.keys()): print k,list_dict[k]
... 
(0, 75) 12.0
(38, 86) 17.0
(44, 65) 13.0
(65, 127) 27.0
(75, 38) 16.0
(85, 44) 45.0
(86, 119) 6.0
(119, 85) 31.0
```